# functioning of horizontal oriented radio buttons

Tags: android, xml

I have placed Customized radio Buttons Horizontally

```
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:checked="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Breakfast" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Lunch" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Dinner" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

---

**yourbuttonbackground.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/b"
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/a"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/a"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/b" />
</selector>
```

**b.xml**

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="#fff" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#555555" />
</shape>
```

**a.xml**

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="#fff" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#53aade" />
</shape>
```

---

**I had a wired error** ::

- when i used above functionality for vertical orientation of radio
     buttons .... it was working perfectly
- But when i placed them horizontally .... it doesn't seem to work

A snapshot below will give a clear idea whats happening , clearly we can see 2 buttons selected. how can i resolve this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last RadioButton is outside of your RadioGroup, It should be inside.